# Vuetify / autocomplete : styling group

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to style the groups displaying in the autocomplete vuetify component. Here is the example of the vuetify Autocomplete component : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#autocomplete

```
<v-autocomplete
              v-model="friends"
              :disabled="isUpdating"
              :items="people"
              box
              chips
              color="blue-grey lighten-2"
              label="Select"
              item-text="name"
              item-value="name"
              multiple
            >
              <template v-slot:selection="data">
                <v-chip
                  :selected="data.selected"
                  close
                  class="chip--select-multi"
                  @input="remove(data.item)"
                >
                  <v-avatar>
                    <img :src="data.item.avatar">
                  </v-avatar>
                  {{ data.item.name }}
                </v-chip>
              </template>
              <template v-slot:item="data">
                <template v-if="typeof data.item !== 'object'">
                  <v-list-tile-content v-text="data.item"></v-list-tile-content>
                </template>
                <template v-else>
                  <v-list-tile-avatar>
                    <img :src="data.item.avatar">
                  </v-list-tile-avatar>
                  <v-list-tile-content>
                    <v-list-tile-title v-html="data.item.name"></v-list-tile-title>
                    <v-list-tile-sub-title v-html="data.item.group"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
                  </v-list-tile-content>
                </template>
              </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
```

with the data :

```
people: [
          { header: 'Group 1' },
          { name: 'Sandra Adams', group: 'Group 1', avatar: srcs[1] },
          { name: 'Ali Connors', group: 'Group 1', avatar: srcs[2] },
          { name: 'Trevor Hansen', group: 'Group 1', avatar: srcs[3] },
          { name: 'Tucker Smith', group: 'Group 1', avatar: srcs[2] },
          { divider: true },
          { header: 'Group 2' },
          { name: 'Britta Holt', group: 'Group 2', avatar: srcs[4] },
          { name: 'Jane Smith ', group: 'Group 2', avatar: srcs[5] },
          { name: 'John Smith', group: 'Group 2', avatar: srcs[1] },
          { name: 'Sandra Williams', group: 'Group 2', avatar: srcs[3] }
        ],
```

Here is the default style :

[image]

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is an option to style the subheader, but you can style it using css.

```css
.v-autocomplete-content .v-select-list .v-subheader {
    color: blue;
}
```